# Is there any virtual 7.1 or 5.1 surround sound software for Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

There are some software for us to virtual the 7.1 or 5.1 surround sound for headphones in Windows, such as Razer Surround, so I can watch movies with 7.1 surround sound.

Is there anything like this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it depends on your hardware - if your machine is capable of highdefinition sound reproduction it is part of the sound driver.

Open Sound Settings:
[image]

Go to Configuration, pull-down Profile for the wanted controller!
[image]

Now select the wanted Surround output.
Turn up the volume, and enjoy!
Happy Ubunting ;-)

Comment: Where do I get this Sound Settings?

Comment: I didn't mean the real surround sound, it's the virtual surround sound that I can hear it in my stereo headset, but still thanks for your answer.

Comment: In order to get this Sound Settings, sudo apt-get install pavucontrol